# Error converting data type varchar to numeric (Newbie)

Tags: sql

I am new to this so be gentle. I am running this script to update a column that's blank with a 108. The column is set to `numeric(18, 0)`. why am I getting this message and how can I get past it.

```
Update HL7ManagerRecords
set ScheduleID = 108
where ScheduleID =''
```

Comment: As a note, you should tag which "flavor" of SQL you're using.  "SQL" encompasses MySQL, MSSQL, Sybase, etc...  Also, the below answers are correct; when you do `ScheduleID = ''`, you are comparing ScheduleID to a string.  Try `Where ScheduleID IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `ScheduleID` is set to `numeric(18, 0)` but you try to find all records where  `ScheduleID` equals an empry string:  `where ScheduleID =''`.

Use `IS NULL` instead

```
Update HL7ManagerRecords
set ScheduleID = 108
where ScheduleID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be the fields is null

```
Update HL7ManagerRecords
set ScheduleID = 108
where ScheduleID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post the schema for the Table. My assumption is ScheduleID is a numeric. Since it is a numeric the ScheduleID is not blank, because it holds a number [numeric MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). My assumption is it is `null`, because that is the default value if you create a `numeric` column and do not specify if it is `null` or not. So what you will need to do is

```
Update HL7ManagerRecords
set ScheduleID = 108
where ScheduleID is null
```

Comment: @JohnMolina happy that it did!

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason down the line you need to take a numeric data type and treat it as a blank string or change it to a string with a specific value, you could use something like ISNULL(ScheduleID,'') = ''. Like the other guys said, "is null" will work just fine, just another way to do it.